# Combining drawRect: with other UIKit drawing

Tags: uikit, core-graphics, drawrect

I'm working on some other person's code, which does most of the UI drawing in `drawRect:`. However, I need to add some animations (`UIActivityIndicator` animating, for example) to the view, and since drawRect: appears to be frame based, there doesn't seem to be an easy way.

I understand it is a mistake to fiddle with view hierarchies in drawRect, so I can't simply `addSubview:`. I want the activity indicator to do its own drawing, after `drawRect:`, because it should overlap. How should I approach this?